# Get int values from string C

Tags: c, parsing

My program receives a string with this format:
`char* s = "(char)=(int1)+(int2)"` like `char* s = "x=11+12"`
and I need to get the two ints to two vars like `var1` and `var2`.

I was iterating the string but it doesnt work to numbers bigger than 9.

EXAMPLE:

```
char* buffer = NULL;
size_t buffsize = 32;
ssize_t aux;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
  printf("FILE ERROR\n");
  return 0;
}
aux = getline(&buffer, &buffersize, fp);
//aux = "x=2+10"

fclose(fp);
```

I expect `var1 = 2` ; `var2 = 10`

Comment: `sscanf()` is an okay starting point.

Comment: Im reading lines from file using getline() so I cant use sscanf().

Comment: please post a [mcve].  THanks

Comment: Please explain how getline() prevents sscanf().

Comment: How do I use sscanf() then?

Comment: something similar to `varcount = sscanf (buffer,"%*s %d %*s %d",&var, &var);`. The return value will tell you if you successully parsed two numbers.

Comment: `sscanf (buffer,"%*s %d %*s %d",&var, &var);` only work if  the string is "x= 2 + 10".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a simple solution using `sscanf` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc,char *argv[])
{
   int var1,var2;
   char *buffer=NULL,c;
   size_t bufsize = 32;
   size_t characters;
   FILE *fp;
   if( argc != 2)
      return -1;
   buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
   fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
   if( fp == NULL)
     return -2;

   characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,fp);
   buffer[characters-1]='\0';
   sscanf( buffer, "aux = \"%c=%d+%d\"",&c,&var1, &var2 );
   printf("var1 = %d , var2 = %d \n",var1,var2);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! By the way is there anyway to change "x" to accept any letter? Like "(letter)=%d+%d".

Comment: I've just edited with it , sscanf( buffer, "aux = \"%c=%d+%d\"",&c,&var1, &var2 );, where c is a simple char , @xPudimx Glad I could help. Feel free to vote this answer if you found it useful.